# Android File Explorer Bug

Tags: java, android

when I open a file explorer(DDMS) in eclipse and then click data / data and I can't see the packages I see only the empty folders called "con".How can I fix that ? Here is a screenshot from my data folder.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Android which belongs to Android Enthusiasts

Answer (score 3):

You need to make name column wider.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't work :(